# composer and git directory structure for project with plugins

Tags: git, composer-php, directory-structure

I've a project with the following structure:

```
- Root
  - actions
  - core
  - other_dir_1
  - other_dir_2
  - vendor [created by composer]
  - file1.php
  - file2.php and so on
```

When using the project, he looks in the actions directory for "installed" plugin (basically other directory with a specific structure).
I want to give to other people the possibility to create own plugins and import into the project.
What i want is that the core files of plugin will be copied into actions directory and if the plugin has dependendy, those will be copied into vendor directory.

So a user can do:

```
git clone  "myproject"
composer require otherVendor/actionOne
composer require otherVendor2/action3  and so on
```

How can I do that?

P.S. the need is:

In the root dir, there is a class to be used in this way:

```
  $actionToRun = "CustomPlug";
  $c = new WrapperClass($actionToRun);
  $c->run();
```

WrapperClass will check if the following exists:   `"action/CustomPlug/CustomPlugAction.php"` and if exists call `CustomPlugAction::run()`

So the idea is to gave to end user the possibility to simply call `"composer require othervendor/customAction"`(separating the core code of plugin, from the needed vendor of plugin) and then launch his plugin with just a change of string

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "plugins"? Why do you need them to be in `actions` directory? How could you use change your design, so it can be installed to `vendor` ?

Comment: Edited the question for more clarify